# How to add inline CSS to dynamically created elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add inline CSS to the left and right messages that are generated, for example the left text is red and the right text is blue. (I know it's best to style in the CSS, but I'm testing something else). So I will have this HTML:

```
<ul class="messages">
  <li class="message left appeared">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text" style="color:red;">blabla</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="message right appeared">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text" style="color:blue;">blabla</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please see the code as reference for the functionality. Many thanks for your help.

```js
(function() {
  var Message;

  Message = function({
      text: text1,
      message_side: message_side1
    }) {
    this.text = text1;
    this.message_side = message_side1;
    this.draw = () => {
      var $message;
      $message = $($('.message_template').clone().html());
      $message.addClass(this.message_side).find('.text').html(this.text);
      $('.messages').append($message);
      return setTimeout(function() {
        return $message.addClass('appeared');
      }, 0);
    };
    return this;
  };

  $(function() {
    var getMessageText, message_side, sendMessage;
    message_side = 'right';
    getMessageText = function() {
      var $message_input;
      $message_input = $('.message_input');
      return $message_input.val();
    };
    sendMessage = function(text) {
      var $messages, message;
      if (text.trim() === '') {
        return;
      }
      $('.message_input').val('');
      $messages = $('.messages');
      message_side = message_side === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
      message = new Message({text, message_side});
      message.draw();
      return $messages.animate({
        scrollTop: $messages.prop('scrollHeight')
      }, 300);
    };
    $('.send_message').click(function(e) {
      return sendMessage(getMessageText());
    });
    $('.message_input').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) { // enter key
        return sendMessage(getMessageText());
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chat_window {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 440px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.messages {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 347px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.messages .message {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.left .text_wrapper::before {
  right: 100%;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.left .text,
.messages .message.right .text {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.right .text_wrapper::before {
  left: 100%;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.appeared {
  opacity: 1;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message .text_wrapper:before {
  top: 18px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after {
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::before {
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbdc0;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper .message_input {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: absolute;
  outline-width: 0;
  color: gray;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.message_template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat_window">
  <ul class="messages"></ul>
  <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="message_input_wrapper">
      <input class="message_input" placeholder="Type here..." />
    </div>
    <div class="send_message">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
        Send
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message_template">
  <li class="message">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any color or messages show up in your example when I run the code snippet. Not really sure what behavior you're hoping for.

Comment: @Marc I'm looking to have two different colours of messages that get styled in html with inline css. If you type in the box (you may need to see it in full page) you can generate messages but they aren't styled because I'd like to do this with js/jQuery - if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set CSS properties such as `color` in jQuery with `.css()`.  Example:

```
$("li.message.left > div.text_wrapper > p").css('color', 'red');
```

```js
(function() {
  var Message;

  Message = function({
      text: text1,
      message_side: message_side1
    }) {
    this.text = text1;
    this.message_side = message_side1;
    this.draw = () => {
      var $message;
      $message = $($('.message_template').clone().html());
      $message.addClass(this.message_side).find('.text').html(this.text);
      $('.messages').append($message);
      $("li.message.left > div.text_wrapper > p").css('color', 'red');
      $("li.message.right > div.text_wrapper > p").css('color', 'blue');
      
      return setTimeout(function() {
        return $message.addClass('appeared');
      }, 0);
    };
    return this;
  };

  $(function() {
    var getMessageText, message_side, sendMessage;
    message_side = 'right';
    getMessageText = function() {
      var $message_input;
      $message_input = $('.message_input');
      return $message_input.val();
    };
    sendMessage = function(text) {
      var $messages, message;
      if (text.trim() === '') {
        return;
      }
      $('.message_input').val('');
      $messages = $('.messages');
      message_side = message_side === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
      message = new Message({text, message_side});
      message.draw();
      return $messages.animate({
        scrollTop: $messages.prop('scrollHeight')
      }, 300);
    };
    $('.send_message').click(function(e) {
      return sendMessage(getMessageText());
    });
    $('.message_input').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) { // enter key
        return sendMessage(getMessageText());
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chat_window {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 440px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.messages {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 347px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.messages .message {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.left .text_wrapper::before {
  right: 100%;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.left .text,
.messages .message.right .text {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}
.messages .message.right .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message.right .text_wrapper::before {
  left: 100%;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
}
.messages .message.appeared {
  opacity: 1;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message .text_wrapper:before {
  top: 18px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after {
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::before {
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbdc0;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper .message_input {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: absolute;
  outline-width: 0;
  color: gray;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.message_template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat_window">
  <ul class="messages"></ul>
  <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="message_input_wrapper">
      <input class="message_input" placeholder="Type here..." />
    </div>
    <div class="send_message">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="text">
        Send
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message_template">
  <li class="message">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p class="text"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I implement this in the code please? I tried but no luck... Thank you